# changing variables to network order when writing raw data to file

Tags: c++, networking

I am using a file to store a struct, I simply write raw data to it, casting variables to char* and passing their address to write

```
virtual void write(ostream& os){
 UINT loTmpVal = value();
 os.write((char*)&loTmpVal, sizeof(loTmpVal));
}
```

I am wondering whether or not i should use hton convertions to change the order of the bytes to network order.

p.s. of course i will use a simple read to get the variables one by one.

Comment: Using network byte order to overcome endianess issues when the data would be read by different machines surely is good idea. It however does not keep you from getting in trouble if there were other difference between those different machines accessing the data, as integer sizes for example.

Answer (score 0):

It's not enforced but is a good idea. As good as just choosing a single byte order for all your clients. It doesn't really matter whether it's LSB or MSB while you're persistent.

However, if you choose to use `hton()` on sending, you have to use `ntoh()` on the other side while receiving.

Answer (score 0):

When to use a specific byte order:

- different machines may read/write the same file
- any time the data is transmitted to another machine

When to use native byte order:

- the data read/write is always done on the same machine

Using native byte order can simplify the code (you could potentially read/write an entire struct at once)

Using a specific byte order (such as network byte order) allows the workload to be distributed and data to be shared.  If this may be a future use case, then it is better to start out that way.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is always used on the same machine, performing  `hton()` only could slow things down.

But "always used on the same machine" is a future prediction and maybe your code or data will get used in a situation never planned.

Further "could slow things down" is premature optimization, maybe the cost is negligible even for a machine that needs to reverse the order.

Suggest either:

1. Use network order

   or if it slows things down to much:
2. Include in the top of the file information to indicate endian-ness used and integer size.  [.tif files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format#Byte_order) used this approach.